# ASP.NET Core Large Data Set Processing

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, lambda, .net-core

I have an Asp.net core 2.1 application with a Postgresql database. 
A large file (~100K lines) gets uploaded to the database and then each line is processed.

As each line is processed there are approximately 15 sub queries per line taking up about 10 seconds in total per line. I have tried optimizing the queries and loading certain datasets in memory to reduce database calls which has seen a slight improvement. I have also tried reducing the batch size but that has also had minimal reduction.

Are there any other ways I can speed this up? The queries are written in lambda.

The high level function:

```
public void CDR_Insert(List<InputTable> inputTable, IQueryable<Costing__Table> CostingTable, List<Patterns> PatternsTable, IQueryable<Country_Calling_Codes> CallingCodesTable, IQueryable<Country> CountryTable, string voicemail_number)
        {

            foreach (var row in inputTable)
            {
                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.finalCalledPartyPattern))
                //{
                var rowexists = _context.CDR.Where(m => m.InputId == row.id).Count();
                if (rowexists == 0)
                {


                    if (ValidateIfOneNumberIsForCountry(row.callingPartyNumber, row.finalCalledPartyNumber, PatternsTable, CountryTable) == true)
                    {
                        var CallRingTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Ring_Time(row.dateTimeOrigination, row.dateTimeConnect));

                        var Call_Direction = CallDirection(row.callingPartyNumber, row.finalCalledPartyNumber, row.finalCalledPartyPattern, voicemail_number);
                        var CallReason = "Destination Out Of Order";
                        if (row.dateTimeConnect != "0")
                        {
                            CallReason = Call_Reason(row.callingPartyNumber, row.originalCalledPartyNumber, row.finalCalledPartyNumber, voicemail_number);
                        }
                        var CallOutcome = Outcome(row.duration, row.dateTimeOrigination, row.dateTimeConnect, row.callingPartyNumber, row.originalCalledPartyNumber, row.finalCalledPartyNumber, voicemail_number);
                        var CallCategory = GetCategory(row.callingPartyNumber, row.finalCalledPartyNumber, PatternsTable, CallingCodesTable, CountryTable);
                        var CallCost = 0.00;


                        if (CallOutcome != "Not Connected" || CallOutcome != "No answer")
                        {
                            CallCost = Costing(row.callingPartyNumber, row.finalCalledPartyNumber, row.dateTimeConnect, row.dateTimeDisconnect, row.finalCalledPartyPattern, row.duration, Call_Direction, CostingTable, PatternsTable, voicemail_number, CallingCodesTable, CountryTable);
                        }

                        CDR cDR = new CDR()
                        {
                            Date_Time = UnixTimeStampToDateTimeConvertor2(row.dateTimeOrigination),
                            Call_Direction = Call_Direction,
                            Calling_Party = row.callingPartyNumber_uri,
                            Calling_Digits = row.callingPartyNumber,
                            Called_Party = row.finalCalledPartyNumber_uri,
                            Called_Digits = row.finalCalledPartyNumber,
                            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(row.duration)),
                            Cost = CallCost,
                            Reason = CallReason,
                            Outcome = CallOutcome,
                            Country_Code = "MUS",//_context.Country.Where(o => o.CountryCode == _CDRExtension.CountryCodeId(_CDRExtension.Call_Type_Id(row.callingPartyNumber))).Select(o => o.CountryCode).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Second_Ring_Time = CallRingTime,
                            Category = CallCategory,
                            CiscoInputId = row.id
                        };

                        _context.CDR.Add(cDR);
                    }
                    row.Processed = true;
                    row.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
                    _context.Cisco_Input.Update(row);

                    // }

                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you give a code example of the kind of lambda operations you are doing?

Comment: Its always a good idea to use stored procedures and avoid lambda queries when there is a lot of processing involved  and try to load as much data  or do as much operation as you can in one  call 
Im not sure about Postgresql  but for sql server i was using table valued parameter passed to stored procedure when it comes to bulk inserting or updating you can also use custom temp tables for your sub queries that is involved in processing

Comment: I've added a code extract. What happens is, the raw data is first uploaded into a "staging" table. From there the new information is processed through multiple queries and calculations. Not sure if stored procedures will work for this.

Comment: @user2806570 loading data in memory results in *orders of magnitude worse performance*. An in-memory array has none of the indexes a database has. And 100K rows is a tiny amount of data. Typical data marts have several millions of rows *per fact table*

Comment: `As each line is processed there are approximately 15 sub queries per line taking` that's the problem right there. Essentially, you're using a client-side cursor instead of  set-based queries. Using an *ORM* for what is essentially an ETL job is a bad idea too. The common way to deal with such data processing jobs is to load the data into staging tables using whatever bulk insert mechanism is available (eg SqlBulkCopy or bcp in SQL Server, COPY in PostgreSQL) and then transform the data in the database before loading into the final tables. That's essentially ELT (Extract, Load, Transform)

Comment: ETL means transforming records before storing them to the database. This *doesn't* mean loading everything in memory, it means extracting the data from the source record by record in a stream, modifying each record and sending it to the database. The aim is to hold as *little* data as possible in memory, touch the database as little as possible. Again, complex processing should only happen in the database.

Comment: For example, if those 15 queries are essentialy lookups, you could load the 15 lookup tables in memory (if they are small enough), match each record as you read it from the source and write it out to the database. With a large dimension table though, cahcing the entire table in memory may not be feasible.